# Unable to post google onSignIn data using ajax in php

Tags: php, google-signin

Am trying to post google `onSignIn` to my database using ajax when i run localhost everything works fine but when i try in web server no data is post in data base just null is passed.

Can someone help me why am not able to insert data to `DB` in web server. When i can insert data in local host.

in web server i can able to see login details in `log.console` but am not able to `$_POST` in `PHP`

**script**

```
         function onSignIn(googleUser) {
            var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            if (profile) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'social.php',
                    data: {
                        name: profile.getName(),
                        mail: profile.getEmail(),
                        img: profile.getImageUrl()
                    }
                }).done(function (data) {
                    console.log(profile.getName());
                    console.log(profile.getEmail());
                    console.log(profile.getImageUrl());

                }).fail(function () {
                    alert("Something went wrong !!");
                });
            }
        }
```

**PHP**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/include/config.php");

$_SESSION["name"] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION["email"] = $_POST['mail'];
$_SESSION["img"] = $_POST['img'];

$email = strip_tags($_POST['mail']);
// The request is using the POST method

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sociall WHERE email=:email");
$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email));
$count = $stmt->rowCount();

if ($count > 0) {
    //email used
} else {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sociall (username, email, socialID, img) VALUES (:username, :email, :socialID, :img)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);
    $stmt->bindParam(':img', $_POST['img'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 200);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {

    }exit;
}
```

i also tried `$_GET` method but does nothing.

i get following error

```
Undefined index: id in C:\Users\Amin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OLX\ads\login\social.php on line 8
Undefined index: name in C:\Users\Amin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OLX\ads\login\social.php on line 9 
Undefined index: mail in C:\Users\Amin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OLX\ads\login\social.php on line 10
Undefined index: img in C:\Users\Amin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OLX\ads\login\social.php on line 11
Undefined index: mail in C:\Users\Amin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OLX\ads\login\social.php on line 13
```

Comment: What have you done so far to try and debug this then? (And why are you ignoring what it says right at the beginning of https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetbasicprofile, _“Do not use the user's profile information to communicate the currently signed in user to your backend server. Instead, send ID tokens, which can be securely validated on the server.”_ …?)

Comment: @04FS hope i can store username and email, because there is need to store name and email. and even with updated code am not able to store data,

Comment: No one is saying you should not store them - but you should request them from the API on the server side, otherwise I can send whatever data I like to your script, and create _fake_ accounts. _“and even with updated code am not able to store data”_ - I asked you what you actually tried to _debug_ this. Removing a random line and hoping that it will work then, it not really debugging …

Comment: am just beginner and i tried `var_dump($_POST) ` not shows and tried only `log.console` please let me know any other debugging method that would be usefull

Comment: `var_dump($_POST) not shows`...where did you look for the result? Don't forget,you're doing this via AJAX, so the output does not show up in the browser window directly, instead it becomes part of the response coming back to the AJAX call. So...open your browser's Developer Tools, go to the Network section. Then run your code and watch for the AJAX call appearing in the list. Click it, and then open the "Response" tab for the call. There you can see any and all output produced by the PHP, including echo, var_dump, exception messages etc.

Comment: @ADyson this is what i see in `network->XHR->preview->` i get this error `Notice: Undefined index: name in /storage/ssd2/859/10067859/public_html/ads/login/social.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: mail in /storage/ssd2/859/10067859/public_html/ads/login/social.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: img in /storage/ssd2/859/10067859/public_html/ads/login/social.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: mail in /storage/ssd2/859/10067859/public_html/ads/login/social.php on line 12`

Comment: Ok so those messages mean that there are no POST values being sent to the server with those names. Now, please check the request parameters for the same AJAX call to see what was _sent_ by the browser. (you'll see this at the bottom of the "Headers" tab in the "form data" section)

Comment: @ADyson yes but how come when i try in localhost there are post data stored in `database`.

Comment: Since I can't see your environments, or any difference between them, I can't answer that. Like I said, you need to trace it back and debug where the data is supposed to come from, and that might help you see understand which part of the code is failing to populate it. Perhaps it's something to do with the google setup, because that seems like a likely reason for a difference across environments.

Comment: @ADyson you can find demo here. http://safebrowser.tk/ads/login/googlelogin

Comment: I'm not going to spend a lot of time to sit with your site and debug it for you, sorry. You can hire a consultant for that, if you don't want to do it yourself. I'm happy to answer questions based on information provided **here**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jQuery code please use `method` instead of `type`:

```
method: 'POST',
```

Then you can use `$_POST` variables.

Comment: Depends on jQuery version, `An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.`